# How to change position of grid items based on higher number of clicks on item

Tags: android

I have grid with 100 number of items based on number of times item click i want to rearrange the item to first position which items have higher number of clicks in descending order

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
ValueComparator bvc = new ValueComparator(map);
TreeMap<String, Integer> sorted_map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(bvc);

map.put("Windows", sharedPref.getInt("Windows", 0));
map.put("iOS", sharedPref.getInt("iOS", 0));
map.put("Android", sharedPref.getInt("Android", 0));
map.put("Blackberry", sharedPref.getInt("Blackberry", 0));
map.put("Java", sharedPref.getInt("Java", 0));
map.put("JQuery", sharedPref.getInt("JQuery", 0));
map.put("Phonegap", sharedPref.getInt("Phonegap", 0));
map.put("SQLite", sharedPref.getInt("SQLite", 0));
map.put("Thread", sharedPref.getInt("Thread", 0));
map.put("Video", sharedPref.getInt("Video", 0));
sorted_map.putAll(map);

iconList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Map<String, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(sorted_map);

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() 
                                  + " Value : " + entry.getValue());


sortedList.add(entry.getKey());

}
```

Comment: change the item order in your list or array and call notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: thank you kalyan. I tried with that, in this case i have to change the array order 100 times , is there any simple logic to get it done

Comment: If you are using ArrayList then you can directly use add(),remove() with position..

Comment: you are correct kalyan ,but in my case it is not usefull , based on number of clicks i want to sort the item list

Comment: can you provide your code..Collections.sort(list) is a way..which is more faster

Comment: now i provided my code

Comment: just find out best sorting algorithm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem
     package com.androidexample.gridview;

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Comparator;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map;
 import java.util.TreeMap;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.GridView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class GridViewExample extends Activity {

    GridView gridView;
    private Map<String, Integer> iconMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int count0 = 0, count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0, count5 = 0,
            count6 = 0, count7 = 0, count8 = 0;
    static final String[] GRID_DATA = new String[] { "Windows", "iOS",
            "Android", "Blackberry", "Java", "JQuery", "Phonegap", "SQLite",
            "Thread", "Video" };

    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    Editor editor;
    ArrayList<Integer> iconList;
    ArrayList<String> sortedList;
    String[] sorted_data;
    public GridViewExample() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        iconMap.put("Windows", R.drawable.windows_logo);
        iconMap.put("iOS", R.drawable.ios_logo);
        iconMap.put("Android", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        iconMap.put("Blackberry", R.drawable.blackberry_logo);
        iconMap.put("Java", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        iconMap.put("JQuery", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        iconMap.put("Phonegap", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        iconMap.put("SQLite", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        iconMap.put("Thread", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        iconMap.put("Video", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_view_android_example);

        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("payism", MODE_APPEND);
        sortedList=new ArrayList<String>();

        File f = new File("/data/data/" + getPackageName()
                + "/shared_prefs/payism.xml");

        if (f.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file exist", 100).show();
        } else {
            editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putInt("Windows", 0);
            editor.putInt("iOS", 0);
            editor.putInt("Android", 0);
            editor.putInt("Blackberry", 0);
            editor.putInt("Java", 0);
            editor.putInt("JQuery", 0);
            editor.putInt("Phonegap", 0);
            editor.putInt("SQLite", 0);
            editor.putInt("Thread", 0);
            editor.putInt("Video", 0);
            editor.commit();
        }

        // Get gridview object from xml file
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        // Set custom adapter (GridAdapter) to gridview
        gridView.setAdapter(new CustomGridAdapter(this, GRID_DATA));



        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                if (((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label)).getText()
                        .toString() == "Windows") {

                    count0 = sharedPref.getInt("Windows", 0);
                    count0 = count0 + 1;
                    editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putInt("Windows", count0);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "hi" + sharedPref.getInt("Windows", 0), 100).show();
                    editor.commit();

                } else if (((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
                        .getText().toString() == "iOS") {

                    int count1 = sharedPref.getInt("iOS", 0);
                    count1 = count1 + 1;
                    editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putInt("iOS", count1);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "hi" + sharedPref.getInt("iOS", 0), 100).show();
                    editor.commit();

                } else if (((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
                        .getText().toString() == "Android") {

                    int count2 = sharedPref.getInt("Android", 0);
                    count2 = count2 + 1;
                    editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putInt("Android", count2);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "hi" + sharedPref.getInt("Android", 0), 100).show();
                    editor.commit();

                } else if (((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
                        .getText().toString() == "Blackberry") {

                    int count3 = sharedPref.getInt("Blackberry", 0);
                    count3 = count3 + 1;
                    editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putInt("Blackberry", count3);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "hi" + sharedPref.getInt("Blackberry", 0), 100)
                            .show();
                    editor.commit();

                } else if (((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
                        .getText().toString() == "Java") {

                    int count4 = sharedPref.getInt("Java", 0);
                    count4 = count4 + 1;
                    editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putInt("Java", count4);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "hi" + sharedPref.getInt("Java", 0), 100).show();
                    editor.commit();

                } else if (((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
                        .getText().toString() == "JQuery") {

                    int count5 = sharedPref.getInt("JQuery", 0);
                    count5 = count5 + 1;
                    editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putInt("JQuery", count5);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "hi" + sharedPref.getInt("JQuery", 0), 100).show();
                    editor.commit();

                } else if (((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
                        .getText().toString() == "Phonegap") {

                    int count6 = sharedPref.getInt("Phonegap", 0);
                    count6 = count6 + 1;
                    editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putInt("Phonegap", count6);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "hi" + sharedPref.getInt("Phonegap", 0), 100)
                            .show();
                    editor.commit();

                } else if (((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
                        .getText().toString() == "SQLite") {

                    int count7 = sharedPref.getInt("SQLite", 0);
                    count7 = count7 + 1;
                    editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putInt("SQLite", count7);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "hi" + sharedPref.getInt("SQLite", 0), 100).show();
                    editor.commit();

                } else if (((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
                        .getText().toString() == "Thread") {

                    int count8 = sharedPref.getInt("Thread", 0);
                    count8 = count8 + 1;
                    editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putInt("Thread", count8);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "hi" + sharedPref.getInt("Thread", 0), 100).show();
                    editor.commit();

                }

                else if (((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
                        .getText().toString() == "Video") {

                    int count9 = sharedPref.getInt("Video", 0);
                    count9 = count9 + 1;
                    editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putInt("Video", count9);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "hi" + sharedPref.getInt("Video", 0), 100).show();
                    editor.commit();

                }
            }
        });
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        ValueComparator bvc = new ValueComparator(map);
        TreeMap<String, Integer> sorted_map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(bvc);

        map.put("Windows", sharedPref.getInt("Windows", 0));
        map.put("iOS", sharedPref.getInt("iOS", 0));
        map.put("Android", sharedPref.getInt("Android", 0));
        map.put("Blackberry", sharedPref.getInt("Blackberry", 0));
        map.put("Java", sharedPref.getInt("Java", 0));
        map.put("JQuery", sharedPref.getInt("JQuery", 0));
        map.put("Phonegap", sharedPref.getInt("Phonegap", 0));
        map.put("SQLite", sharedPref.getInt("SQLite", 0));
        map.put("Thread", sharedPref.getInt("Thread", 0));
        map.put("Video", sharedPref.getInt("Video", 0));
        sorted_map.putAll(map);

        iconList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Map<String, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(sorted_map);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() 
                                       + " Value : " + entry.getValue());


            sortedList.add(entry.getKey());


        }

        for(int i=0;i<sortedList.size();i++)
        {

            GRID_DATA[i]=sortedList.get(i);
            Log.d("Completed Sorted List Items are", GRID_DATA[i]);
        }

    }
    public static void printMap(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() 
                                       + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
            entry.getKey();

        }
    }
 }

 class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Integer> base;

    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Integer> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
 }
```